# Jersey resource class serving multiple paths

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have written a resource class with which I want to support multiple resource paths.

```
@Path("/path/to/jobs")
public class JobController {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<JobDto> getJobs() {
        ...
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("{job_id}")
    public JobDto getJob() {
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that this accepts the path `localhost:80/path/to/jobs`but not `localhost:80/path/to/jobs/job123`. I have tried annotating the class with `/path/to` and the methods with `jobs` and `jobs/{job_id}`. It still doesn't work. Any pointers?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4784028/341008) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21980244/341008) which seem to suggest I should be able to do this.

Comment: So you are getting a 404? I can't think of any reason for this to result in a 404, given `getJobs` works.

Comment: @peeskillet yes I am getting `404`. That's what I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Now it accepts

> localhost:80/path/to/jobsjob123

. If you want to get response with

> localhost:80/path/to/jobs/job123

annotate the getJob() method with

> @Path("/{job_id}")

You just missed the "/"